# SQL Server Count Occurrences of a value of colounns

Tags: asp.net, sql, count, rdlc

Thank you for taking time to read this.

I have a `ServiceDetails` Table which have columns like

```
ID, ServiceID , ClientID... , Status ,IsFollowUp
```

and Services have

```
ID, Date , CityID, AreaID
```

Now when a service request is entered , its status is either `'pending', 'Completed','testing', or 'indeteriminent'`.

Now end user wants a report that

City, Area , TotalServices , Total Completed without followup , Total Completed at First followup, Total Completed at 2nd followup ... , Total Completed at Fifth followup

I have Completed uptill now, Total Completed without `followup` but how do I calculate the `Completed` services `followups` count.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP#(
    [ID] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Area] varchar(250),
    [City] varchar(250),
    [Total] int,
    [WithoutFollowup] int,
    [FirstFollowup] int,
    [SecondFollowup] int,
    [ThirdFollowup] int,
    [FourthFollowup] int,
    [FifthFollowup] int
);

    DECLARE @AreaID AS bigint = 0
    DECLARE @CityID AS bigint = 0
    DECLARE @AreaName AS nvarchar(250) = ''
    DECLARE @CityName AS nvarchar(250) = ''

DECLARE @VCCTDetailsID AS bigint = NULL, @ClientID AS bigint = NULL
        ,@TotalTests as int, @WithoutFollowup as int, @FirstFollowup as int,@SecondFollowup as int, @ThirdFollowup as int, @FourthFollowup as int, @FifthFollowup as int
        ,@Org as varchar(250),@City as varchar(250)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 

    SELECT  Areas.ID, Areas.Name, Cities.ID, Cities.CityName
    FROM    [dbo].[Areas]
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[AreaCities] ON Areas.ID = AreaCities.AreaID
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Cities] ON AreaCities.CityID = Cities.ID
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[States] ON States.ID = Cities.StateID
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Countries] ON Countries.ID = States.CountryID
    WHERE   [Areas].[IsActive] = 1
        AND [Cities].[IsActive] = 1
        AND [Areas].[CountryID] = 168

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @AreaID, @AreaName, @CityID, @CityName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @Total = (
            SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM    [dbo].[ServiceDetails]
                INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Services] ON [ServiceDetails].[ServiceID] =  [Services].[ID]
            Where   [ServiceDetails].[Status] !='Testing'
                AND [ServiceDetails].[Status] !='Pending'
                AND [Services].[AreaID] = @AreaID
                AND [Services].[CityID] = @CityID
            GROUP BY    [Services].[AreaID],[Services].[CityID]                                
        )
        SET @WithoutFollowup = (
            SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM    [dbo].[ServiceDetails]
                INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Services] ON [ServiceDetails].[ServiceID] =  [Services].[ID]
            Where   [ServiceDetails].[Status] !='completed'
                AND [ServiceDetails].[IsFollowUp] = 'false'
                AND [Services].[AreaID] = @AreaID
                AND [Services].[CityID] = @CityID
            GROUP BY    [Services].[AreaID],[Services].[CityID]                                
        )
        SET @FirstFollowup = (
            SELECT  COUNT(1)
            FROM    [dbo].[ServiceDetails]
                INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Services] ON [ServiceDetails].[ServiceID] =  [Services].[ID]
            Where   [ServiceDetails].[Status] !='completed'
                AND [ServiceDetails].[IsFollowUp] = 'True'
            GROUP BY    [Services].[AreaID],[Services].[CityID]                              
        )

        INSERT #TEMP# ([Org],[City],[Total],[WithoutFollowup],[FirstFollowup],[SecondFollowup],[ThirdFollowup],[FourthFollowup],[FifthFollowup]) 
        VALUES(@AreaName,@CityName,@Total,@WithoutFollowup,@FirstFollowup,@SecondFollowup,@ThirdFollowup,@FourthFollowup,@FifthFollowup);

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @AreaID, @AreaName, @CityID, @CityName
    END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM #TEMP#    
DROP TABLE #TEMP#
```

Comment: Anyone please ? I just want to count the `occurrences` of `followups` done, how many clients were given `followups` and then status was completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've accomplished this task using `rownumbers` and another `temporary Table` inside the cursor

```
INSERT INTO #Services# 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Services].[Date]) as 'RowNo',[ServiceDetails].* , [Services].[Date]
FROM    [ServiceDetails]
    INNER JOIN  [Services] ON [Services].[ID] = [ServiceDetails].[VCCTsServiceID]
    INNER JOIN  [Clients] ON [Clients].[ID] = [ServiceDetails].[ClientID]
WHERE   [Clients].[ID] LIKE @ClientID       
ORDER BY    [Services].[Date]
```

This `#Services#` is the exact replica of `ServiceDetails` table. Now we have all the services given to the client with `rownumber` and `Date`. It is sorted on date so we get the followups exactly when they are done. Now you can query what you want.

```
SET @TotalServices = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Services# )
SET @FirstSericeDate = (SELECT  [#Services#].[Date] FROM    #Services# WHERE [#Services#].[RowNo] = 1 )
SET @Status = (SELECT [#Services#].[Status] FROM #Services# WHERE [#Services#].[RowNo] = 1 )
SET @Date1 = (SELECT [#Services#].[Date] FROM #Services# WHERE [#Services#].[RowNo] = 2 )
SET @Status1 = (SELECT [#Services#].[Status] FROM #Services# WHERE [#Services#].[RowNo] = 2)
```

Then insert your variables into main `temptable` for reporting

```
INSERT #TEMP# ([RegNo], . . . [Status], Date1], [Status1]  . .)  
VALUES(@RegNo,  . .. @Status, @Date1 , @Status1, . . );
TRUNCATE TABLE #Services#

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @RegNo
```